# How do I plot the likelyhood of an event occurring after X chances?

Tags: graphing-functions

Let's say there's a 1/10 chance of something happening.

Given 1 chance, there's a 0.1 chance of the thing happening.

Given 2 chances, there's a 0.1 + (0.9 * 0.1) chance of the thing happening.

Given 3 chances, there's a ... Help!

Is there any way to plot this, such that given X chances, the chance of the thing happening at least once is Y?

```
f(x) = ...
```

I have also tried for a good hour to graph the opposite, i.e. what are the odds that given X chances, the thing doesn't happen a single time. My uneducated brain can't think of a way to graph any of these without referring to the result of `f(x-1)`, which is not allowed in the graph editor I'm using.

Comment: It's wise to start with the complement probability, that is: What is the probability that, during $n$ trials, the event has not occured? If the probability of the event is $p$ and all the trials are independent, then
$$
P(\text{event not happened during n trials}) = (1-p)^n
$$
After this, you can calculate
$$
P(\text{event occurs at least one during n trials}) = 1-P(\text{event not happened during n trials}) 
$$

Comment: @MattiP. Ah, I didn't notice you edited your comment. How come you didn't just post this as an answer? :)

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out... And considering how simple it turned out to be I'm ashamed it took me over 2 hours.

$$
f(x) = 1 - 0.9^x
$$

[image: Graph]

(Is this correct? Or does it just approximate the correct answer close enough that I fooled myself)

Comment: Well, to be nickpicky, you could restrict $x$ to be an integer ... But otherwise I think it's correct!

Comment: @MattiP. Neat, thanks!